# Scriptable 2D platformer

Tags: mods

Does anyone know a highly scriptable 2D platformer? one that allows creation of entirely new characters, modification of the behavior of the already existing characters, etc. It doesn't really matter if it free or not or if it is or isn't indie.

Comment: This question is considered game-recommendation, and due to it's subjective nature it is considered off-topic on our site as stated in our [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq). You are welcome to ask in our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) though, where you may find users able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played Cortex Command a couple of hours and figured out that there is a lot you can customize/create in the included editors maybe do some research on that? Though I must say it isn't the simplest game to play.